# How does docker handle almost equal images?

Tags: docker

I have two node applications. Each application has its own docker image.

**Image 1**:

- FROM debian
- Install packages (python, supervisor, git)
- Install node
- Install socat
- Install redis_cli
- Git clone app 1

**Image 2**:

- FROM debian
- Install packages (python, supervisor, git)
- Install node
- Install redis_cli
- Git clone app 2

So as you can see both images share the same base image, packages, node and redis_cli.

If I create containers of those images on the same machine, does docker reuse the layers or does it reuse layers only in the scope of an image but not across images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "it depends". If you keep the intermediate images when you build a `Image 1`, docker will reuse them when you build `Image 2`.

You can test this by creating the 2 images and later running the command `docker history [image name]` and you'll see that the hashes of the intermediate layers are the same.

This [blog](http://tuhrig.de/layering-of-docker-images/) explains this in a bit more detail.